# How to copy a generated files from a dependency to the target of current project with maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have tow maven projects `resources-win` and `main-exec`.I try to copy a dll file from a folder `win` of `resources-win` and copy it to `target/classes`, then i moved to the project number 2 `main-exec` and i try to copy a file 2 witch is in `src/main/shcemas` and the dll file of `resources-win` and paste them into target classes of the project `resources-win`

Here is the bloc of code whitch helps to copy a file to target of `resources-win`:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources01</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/win</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.dll</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Here is a part of pom.xml of the project `main-exec`:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-libraries</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <!-- win32 -->
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.resources-win</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ressources-win</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>pom</type>
                                <destFileName>xdol.dll</destFileName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/temp/schemas</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I think you're going at it the wrong way: first of all, just place your DLL file under `src/main/resources` since it is a project resource, and then in `main-exec`, have a real `<dependency>` on `ressources-win` (you don't need the `maven-dependency-plugin`). Then you can access it like any other resources.

Comment: It a project of our company so i can't place it anywhere

Comment: What's exactly is not working ? Nothing is copied ? Copied in the wrong place ?

Comment: i can have the dll file in the target classes of resources-win project but i can't copy it from main-exec project and paste it into the target/classes of main-exec project

Comment: Still... all of this is very unconventional, and your `<artifactItem>` will not work as a result. You're telling to copy the POM file with the name `xdol.dll`, but the DLL isn't your POM file, I assume it's contained inside of a JAR (?) built by `resources-win`. So you'd need to `unpack` its content, rather than copy, to the build directory. In any case, can you provide a full [mcve] of what _exactly_ you're trying to do?

Comment: @Tunaki you are right i forgot the correct pom by dll but can give me more details about unpack?

Comment: See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html. But why do you really absolutely need that file inside `target/classes`? If you need it to be present on the classpath, just have a `<dependency>` in your POM, nothing more is needed.

Comment: i want to use this file in the project main-exec and we will use it in other projects later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like that by using an xsd file by adding to pom.xml of `resources-win`:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources-xsd</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/schemas</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/titi.xsd</file>
                                <type>xsd</type>
                                <classifier>titi</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/toto.xsd</file>
                                <type>xsd</type>
                                <classifier>toto</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then into the pom.xml of `main-exec` i added:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-libraries</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>groupId of resources-win</groupId>
                                <artifactId>artifactId of resources-win</artifactId>
                                <version>${resources-win.version}</version>
                                <type>xsd</type>
                                <classifier>toto</classifier>
                                <destFileName>toto.xsd</destFileName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp/schemas</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I added also the the pom.xml of main-exec the dependency of resources-win.